# Storing modulus in list

Tags: python, hash

I have a list storing hash values. Now i would like to do modulus operation on each element,
like hash[i]%4 and store value in another list.I am using while loop for this operation, but as list is very long the compilation time required is long. Is there any other pythonic way to speed up the process.Code used, x = length of list, hashes : list storing hash values,list5 is a new list.

```
    while t in range(0,x):
       list5[t]=hashes[t]%4
       t=t+1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should take a what are called [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)... `list5 = [el % 4 for el in hashes]`... Apart from that it's unclear what you mean by "speed up"... if you're dealing with a large array of large integers, you may get more value from using a numerical library such as `numpy` that can store fixed size values and make your run-time more predictable....

Answer (score 2):

```
while t in range(0,x):
```

creates a new range object every time it does the test. A more usual construct would be

```
for t in range(0,x):
    list5[t] = hashes[t] % 4
```

This only creates a single range object and moves `t` along it automatically. This has the disadvantage of needing to preallocate a list the correct size. You could append to a list instead

```
list5 = []
for t in range(0,x):
    list5[t].append(hashes[t] % 4)
```

However the Pythonic way is to use a list comprehension

```
list5 = [i % 4 for i in hashes]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more pythonic approach might look like

```
In [1]: x = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [2]: [item%4 for item in x]
Out[2]: [1, 3, 0, 1, 2]
```